# HTML/CSS Navbar Align and Background Color Not Working

Tags: html, css, web, navbar

**Story and What I Am Going For:**

I just finished my full HTML and CSS course and decided I wanted to make a website, obviously. While making this is had a few issues but was able to fix them myself. This one I am curious about. I've tried adding a `style="background-color: black;"` inside the `div` tag. I've also tried multiple things, but it doesn't seem to color in between the left and right buttons of the Navbar. I attached the following below, My *Css File*, *HTML File* and an image of the *Source Output*. I could be having a brain fart but I just need help with this.

***CSS File:***

```css
ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li:last-child {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px 11px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

***HTML File:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="languages.html">Languages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="support.html">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://puginarug.com">An Amazing Website</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    <br>
    <h1>index.html</h1>
</html>
```

***Output:***
[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ul width to 100%, then add background-color: black

```
ul {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%; 
background-color: black;
}
```

Just remove the background-color from the li a selector and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! I thought having an li tag all the way to the right would expand it instead of separating it, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I was confused at first too. So I pulled up dev tools and was able to spot out the problem pretty quick (https://www.codecademy.com/articles/use-devtools). glad it all worked out for you 